# ResignFirstResponder from Keyboard AccessoryView Button

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios

In my View i have 3 UITextField, for each of them i created an accessoryView for keyboard as explained by [apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html).

In my accessoryView i added a button which has to call function "CloseKeyboard". In this function i cant find a way to intercept the UITextField in which keyboard is writing and on which i need to call ResignFristResponder.

To add accessoryView on one field i wrote that code

```
if (field1.inputAccessoryView == nil) {
    field1.inputAccessoryView = [self createInputAccessoryView];   
}
if (field2.inputAccessoryView == nil) {
    field2.inputAccessoryView = [self createInputAccessoryView];   
}
if (field3.inputAccessoryView == nil) {
    field3.inputAccessoryView = [self createInputAccessoryView];   
}
```

And here createInputAccessory function:

```
-(UIView *)createInputAccessoryView {

    CGRect accessFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 20.0, 55.0);

    UIView *inputAccessoryView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:accessFrame];

    UIButton *compButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    compButton.frame = CGRectMake(250.0, 10.0, 60.0, 40.0);

    [compButton setTitle: @"Close" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [compButton addTarget:self action:@selector(CloseKeyboard:)

                        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [inputAccessoryView addSubview:compButton];

return inputAccessoryView; }
```

How can i implement the "CloseKeyboard" function to be able to resignFirstResponder from active UITextField ?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of iOS 2.0 and later, there is an easy way to dismiss the keyboard without having to track the currently active control, or iterating through all the available controls, or using a `UITextFieldDelegate`.

```
[self.view endEditing:YES]
```

From the docs:

> **endEditing:**
>
> Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to
>   resign the first responder status.
>       - (`BOOL`)endEditing:(`BOOL`)*force*
>
> **Parameters**
>   *force*
>  
>   Specify `YES` to force the first responder to resign, regardless of whether it wants to do
>   so. 
>   **Return Value**
>   `YES` if the view resigned the first responder status or `NO` if it did not.
>
> **Discussion**
>  
>   This method looks at the current view and its subview
>   hierarchy for the text field that is currently the first responder. If
>   it finds one, it asks that text field to resign as first responder. If
>   the force parameter is set to `YES`, the text field is never even asked;
>   it is forced to resign.

Answer (score 0):

As first solution i try with this implementation, where i force every time field1 become firstResponder and than i resign it.

```
-(void) closeFunction:(id)sender{   
    [field1 becomeFirstResponder];
    [field1 resignFirstResponder];
}
```

But this's a work around ... not a solution :P